# update anaconda virtual environment to specific python version

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, conda

I installed python 3.7 with anaconda on my unbuntu server, and created a virtual env named py36.  I accidentally created it as a python 2.7 env.  Is there a way to update the virtual env py36 and all it's packages to python 3.5?

Comment: Couldn't you just create a new environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can activate the environment and install whichever version of Python you want:

```
conda activate py36
conda install python=3.X
```

This will automatically update all the packages to the version that you want.

Comment: thank you for getting back to me on this.  I originally created my env from a yml file, not sure how it wound up python 2.7.  will it update all the package dependencies in the virtual env py36?